# Run method on every generic record type in the assembly

Tags: f#, dapper

Getting into the bowels now. Hopefully this is the last time I have to deal with Reflection for a while and I can return to the high level where I belong.

I have a type "PrimaryKey" defined as such.

```
type PrimaryKey<'x> =
    | Id of int
    | EmptyPrimaryKey
```

Then a bunch of record types associated with database tables, for example:

```
type User = {
    user_id: PrimaryKey<User>
    username: string
    email: string
    address_id: PrimaryKey<Address>
} with
    static member DatabaseTable = "users"
```

I have written a custom type handler for Dapper to handle the Primary Key type.

```
type PrimaryKeyHandler<'X>() =
    inherit SqlMapper.TypeHandler<PrimaryKey<'X>>()

    (* I don't think this works but that's a future problem *)
    override _.SetValue(param, value) =
        let valueOrNull =
            match value with
                | PrimaryKey.Id id -> box id
                | EmptyPrimaryKey -> null

        param.Value <- valueOrNull

    override _.Parse value =
        if isNull value || value = box DBNull.Value
        then EmptyPrimaryKey
        else Id (value :?> int)
```

Now the problem with that is I have to call::

```
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler (PrimaryKeyHandler<User>())
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler (PrimaryKeyHandler<OtherRecordType>())
```

On every record that has a primary key. I'm basing my solution off of this: [Dapper generic typehandler for F# Union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591740/dapper-generic-typehandler-for-f-union-types)

But I don't understand it enough to adapt it to my needs, I think I need extra handling for the generic type.

What I've started with is this:

```
let RegisterTypeHandlers ()  =
    let assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
    let handler = typedefof<PrimaryKeyHandler<_>>

    assembly.GetTypes()
        |> Seq.filter(fun t ->
            FSharpType.IsRecord(t) && t.GetProperty("DatabaseTable") <> null
        )
```

Which successfully returns a list of record types which have database table associations.

However trying to iterate over that list and call AddTypeHandler on all of those types fails:

```
let RegisterTypeHandlers ()  =
    let assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()
    let handler = typedefof<PrimaryKeyHandler<_>>

    assembly.GetTypes()
        |> Seq.filter(fun t ->
            FSharpType.IsRecord(t) && t.GetProperty("DatabaseTable") <> null
        )
        |> Seq.iter(fun t ->
            printfn $"Type: {t.Name}"
            let ctor = handler
                        .MakeGenericType(t)
                        .GetConstructor(Array.empty)
                        .Invoke(Array.empty)

            
            (typeof<SqlMapper>.GetMethods()
                |> Seq.filter(fun methodInfo ->
                        if methodInfo.Name = "AddTypeHandler" && methodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition then
                            let gp = methodInfo.GetParameters()
                            not <| isNull gp && gp.Length = 1 && gp.[0].ParameterType.Name.Contains("TypeHandler")
                        else false)
                |> Seq.head)
                .MakeGenericMethod(t)
                .Invoke(null, [| ctor |]) |> ignore
        )
```

The error being

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'MyModule.Common+PrimaryKeyHandler`1[Program+User]' cannot be converted to type 'Dapper.SqlMapper+TypeHandler`1[Program+User]'.
```

I've been looking at some of the GenericType functions in reflection but not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are getting an error saying that `PrimaryKeyHandler<User>` cannot be converted to type `TypeHandler<User>`. This is correct, because your type `PrimaryKeyHandler<User>` inherits from `TypeHandler<PrimaryKey<User>>`.

I think this happens because you get the `AddTypeHandler` method via reflection and then use `MakeGenericMethod(t)` to make it generic - but if `t` is `User`, then you get the wrong generic instantiation - you need to wrap `t` with `PrimaryKey<..>` around it first.

I have not tested this, but I think the following should work:

```
let addTyMi = 
  typeof<SqlMapper>.GetMethods()
  |> Seq.find(fun methodInfo ->
    if methodInfo.Name = "AddTypeHandler" && 
       methodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition then
      let gp = methodInfo.GetParameters()
      not <| isNull gp && gp.Length = 1 &&
        gp.[0].ParameterType.Name.Contains("TypeHandler")
    else false)

let pkt = typedefof<PrimaryKey<_>>.MakeGenericType(t)
addTyMi.MakeGenericMethod(pkt).Invoke(null, [| ctor |]) |> ignore
```

It seems to me that there is also a non-generic overload of `AddTypeHandler` taking `System.Type` (by browsing GitHub source - I have not tried this). Maybe you could do just:

```
let pkt = typedefof<PrimaryKey<_>>.MakeGenericType(t)
SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(pkt, ctor)
```

...avoiding some of the reflection. Also, `ctor` is a bad name, because the variable refers to the instance!

Comment: Thank you!
`let pkt = typedefof<PrimaryKey<_>>.MakeGenericType(t)`
`SqlMapper.AddTypeHandler(pkt, (ctor :?> SqlMapper.ITypeHandler))`

Did the trick! Now just to figure out why the SetValue in the handler function doesn't work and I'm golden!