# F# Custom generic dapper TypeHandler for Discriminated Union Types

Tags: generics, f#, dapper, discriminated-union

I'm trying to write a custom Generic Dapper TypeHandler for discriminated Union types.

For reference see this question : [Dapper generic typehandler for F# Union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591740/dapper-generic-typehandler-for-f-union-types?newreg=5c29ecafdb5c4485b385beb8a439a0fb)

I'm unable to write the Parse method without running into static coercion limitation.

A non generic type handler that works:

```
type DapperIdTypeHandler() =
    inherit SqlMapper.TypeHandler<Id>()

    override this.SetValue(parameter, Id id) = parameter.Value <- id

    override this.Parse(value) = Id(value :?> Guid)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to write the parse method in a generic way?

Here is a code snippet of the generic function that doesn't work:

```
type DapperUnionTypeHandler<'t>() =
    inherit SqlMapper.TypeHandler<'t>()
    override x.Parse(value) =
        // Stuck at this step
        't <| (value :?> Guid)

    override this.SetValue(param, value) =
        param.Value <- value
        ()
```

Union type I'm using:

```
type Id =
    | Id of Guid
```